# glGenVertexArrays() should not have any arguments

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, lwjgl

I am trying to get basic custom shaders working on a LibGDX project.   When I try to generate the VAO it says that `glGenVertexArrays()` requires an int (n) and an IntBuffer (buffer). I know the IntBuffer is how you access the allocated buffer space, but I honestly have no idea what is supposed to go into n. In every example I have found while searching around, `glGenVertexArrays()` is a method with no arguments and just returns the int index for the VAO, which you can use to set it up, bind to it, etc.

How am I supposed to use this to set up a VAO and why is my method signature different than all the other LWJGL examples I have looked at?

Comment: Actually, LWJGL is the library that is not standard compliant. According to the OpenGL specification, `glGenVertexArrays` always takes an integer (the number of VAOs to generate) and a storage segment where the handles get stored.

Answer (score 2):

According to the source for libgdx you can only call it in one of these 3 ways depending on the object:

```
//Normal methods
.glGenVertexArrays(int n, int[] arrays, int offset);
.glGenVertexArrays(int n, IntBuffer arrays);

//Method specifically for AndroidGL30.glGenVertexArrays(...
.glGenVertexArrays (int n, java.nio.IntBuffer arrays);
```

In most cases the `n` is ignored or just used as an array size. The below is copied from the `LwjglGL30` class:

```
@Override
public void glGenVertexArrays (int n, int[] arrays, int offset) {
    for(int i = offset; i < offset + n; i++) {
        arrays[i] = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    }
}

@Override
public void glGenVertexArrays (int n, IntBuffer arrays) {
    GL30.glGenVertexArrays(arrays);
}
```

So from that we can see that for the `IntBuffer` method you can simply use the following in your code: `.glGenVertexArrays(1, myIntBuffer);`

Reference:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=glGenVertexArrays&type=

For more help you should show us a bit more of your code, and what objects you are using to call `glGenVertexArrays()`.

Comment: This all makes sense, but how do you get the int index of the vao back from this to use in glBindBuffers?

Comment: @SamuelO'Brien You could keep track of it yourself by making a simple wrapper with an index value for each object? There is probably a better way to do this, but I dont know enough about opengl to help with that.

Comment: But how do you get the index value for the vao you create. The glGenVertexArrays() has no return value (its void).

Comment: Every time you call glGenVertexArrays the value is increased for the next item, so every time you call it you can assign an index? So maybe have a global variable that is increased every time you call glGenVertexArrays, and save the value of the variable in your object wrapper every time you use glGenVertexArrays, then you can easily reference it later by index? So the first one will be 0, and the fifth one will be index 4